# How do I stop routes for user profile conflicting with other routes in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I stop these 2 routes from clashing:

```
  match "users/:id/edit", :to => "users#edit", :via => :get, :as => :settings
  match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

When I visit localhost:3000/settings it tries to find a user in my users table with the username "settings".

What I plan on doing is having a page settings then have things like settings/privacy, settings/general and also edit_profile

How can I have this but also still get to user localhost:3000/username

It must be possible as I've seen many ROR sites doing this.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings route you have here is pointing to the users edit path.
Using settings_path will direct to users/:id/edit

What you want is:

```
match "/settings", :to => "users#settings"
match "/settings/:category", :to => "users#settings"
match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Now '/settings' will direct you to the settings method.  The second additional route will handle the specific setting to route to (ie /settings/privacy) which will allow you to evaluate what to do in the view based on the params[:category] parameter available in your settings action.  Alternatively this will give a privacy settings path:

```
match "/settings", :to => "users#settings"
match "/settings/privacy", :to => "users#settings", :as => :privacy_settings
match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

No need for the :as statement, settings_path will still work.  Then in the settings method of your UsersController you can use session information(current_user) to render the proper user.

The RESTful edit path will be handled and available through this statement in your routes file:

```
resources :users
```

So 'users/:id/edit' will still work.

Comment: I have the resources :users already but shouldn't users#setting be users#edit?

Comment: You could do that but the edit action will be large as it is having to deal with various conditions of the request.

The REST edit action expects a params[:id] parameter.  If you change the route to '/settings/:id', :to => 'users#edit' it will work as you expect but then you're 'settings/privacy' will change to settings/:id/privacy.

Also I will add a route to my answer that will deal with the various categories of settings.  But I recommend a separate settings action.

Comment: Oh I re-read and I think i get what you mean. I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: @Gregory: You haven't defined a `/settings` route anywhere, you've just created a `users/:id/edit` route that is *called* settings so that `settings_path` references `users/:id/edit`. The `:as` value (which I didn't see) has nothing to do with the with the route's URL.

Comment: Perfect! Your instructions solved my issue. I also noticed my user was being logged out after every update so I just added a login method I have stored in a sessions helper in the update method. Thanks